# Making a <marquee> be screen width

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to set up a  for the top of my site to put something on now and then. However, it doesn’t reach to the ends of my screen which looks odd.[image: marquee image]

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <marquee>Super Bowl Sunday!</marquee>`
```

**CSS**

```
marquee {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

How can I extend this? I tried using `align`, `width`, and `margin` but it doesn’t make it cover the screen and stay centered. Any help would be great. Is this maybe because it’s considered ‘obsolete’? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body `Padding` and `Margin` should be `0`

```css
marquee {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
body
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <marquee>Super Bowl Sunday!</marquee>
    </body
```